# Lenovo T560 Mouse Buttons have no function

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I have an Lenovo T560 running Ubuntu 20.04, I would like to get the mouse buttons above the track pad working, however they do not seem to function, I have tried using `xinput --query-state \<mouse id\>` and pressing the buttons, however they do not register that they have been pressed.

ThinkPad mousepad:

[image: Thinkpad Mousepad]

Any ideas how I can get these buttons working? tapping or pressing the trackpad works as expected, it is just the additional 3 mouse buttons above the trackpad that do nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: Silly question, but you've confirmed that they're not disabled in the Mouse/Pointer settings, yes? I disable mine almost immediately after the OS is installed 

Comment: Hi, Long delay in responding to this I know (have been moving house) no option to disable in settings. I have since upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04  and still no joy getting these buttons to play ball!

Comment: One thing to check, then, would be whether the buttons work at all. If you boot into a Live Session (with the installation USB), do they work? If not, then you may have a hardware issue 

Comment: They do not work in any installations of Linux, but they do in Windows