# Mouse Buttons not working after suspend on Lenovo T560

Tags: 22.04, suspend, mouse, lenovo, thinkpad

I have a problem with my Mouse Buttons of my Lenovo T560 running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

When I place the Laptop into suspend sometimes the Buttons above the touchpad stop working. This seems to be a random occurrence, sometimes they keep working after suspend, sometimes they stop working. [Buttons in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwoxn.jpg) (Image from: [Lenovo T560 Mouse Buttons have no function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401897/lenovo-t560-mouse-buttons-have-no-function))

My current solution is to put the Laptop into suspend repeatedly until I am lucky and the Buttons work again. Restarting or Power down do not seem to have an impact on this behavior, they just take longer to execute.

I have tried fixing the issue following tips from these other questions:

[Ubuntu 18.04 mouse on Lenovo Thinkpad X240 not working after suspend/hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097080/ubuntu-18-04-mouse-on-lenovo-thinkpad-x240-not-working-after-suspend-hibernate)

[Is there a way to "restart" the touchpad driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528293/is-there-a-way-to-restart-the-touchpad-driver)

The result from my **xinput list**:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Running **sudo xinput disable 2** results in:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

I do not know how to handle a "Xwayland server"

Using **modprobe -r psmouse** and **modprobe psmouse** returns no result at all

Any help or ideas on what to try next are greatly appreciated.

Thank you for any replies

**EDIT:** It appears the problem is caused by hardware error, I have replaced one of the rubber feet on the bottom of the laptop, afterwards the problem showed up less.

When I exert a bending force in the opposite direction while the laptop wakes from suspend the problem does not show up. (Force in the opposite direction of the missing rubber feet, e.g. lifting the lower left edge of the keyboard and applying pressure directly underneath the touch pad)

The Problem never shows up when the laptop is in use, even if bending force is applied to the keyboard in any direction.

Maybe this can help anyone with similar problems

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same thing as you; my mouse buttons on touchpad/bluetooth mouse do not work after waking up from almost every suspend (Ubuntu 22.04.3, X11, Lenovo ThinkPad P14s). What I currently use to recover from this state is:

- Switch into another tty where GUI does not run (Ctrl + Alt + F3 for instance).
- Log in and run `sudo udevadm trigger`.

It seems that a mouse button remains clicked when the system is woken up. I would appreciate if someone had a procedure on how to prevent this behavior completely.